# Use 2 different SQL queries in Laravel View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to show 2 columns on my homepage with 2 different

I have a `BrowseController.php` file:

```
 /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTrending()
{
    $posts = $this->posts->getTrending(null, ['category' => Input::get('category'), 'timeframe' => Input::get('timeframe')]);

    return View::make('post.list')->with('title', t('Trending'))->with('posts', $posts);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLatest()
{
    $posts = $this->posts->getLatest(null, ['category' => Input::get('category'), 'timeframe' => Input::get('timeframe')]);
    $title = t('Latest');

    return View::make('post.list', compact('title', 'posts'));
}
```

And a `PostsRepository.php` file:

```
public function getTrending($type = null, $param = [])
{
    isset($param['timeframe']) ? $param['timeframe'] = $param['timeframe'] : $param['timeframe'] = 'month';

    $posts = $this->posts($type, $param)->with('comments', 'votes', 'category', 'user', 'votes.user')
        ->leftJoin('votes', 'posts.id', '=', 'votes.post_id')
        ->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
        ->select('posts.*', DB::raw('count(votes.post_id)*5 as popular'))
        ->groupBy('posts.id')->with('user')->orderBy('popular', 'desc');

    $posts = $posts->paginate(perPage());

    return $posts;
}

public function getLatest($type = null, $param = [])
{
    $posts = $this->posts($type, $param)->with('comments', 'votes', 'category', 'user', 'votes.user')->orderBy('approved_at', 'desc')->paginate(perPage());

    return $posts;
}
```

In my blade php file i'm trying to use this 2 functions but only one is working because in my `routes.php` file i have this:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BrowseController@getLatest']);
```

so `@foreach($posts as $post) @endif` loads only the `getLatest` but not `getTrending`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You've told your route to use the `getTrending()` controller method, but the `getLatest()` call exists in a different method entirely. If you want to show the latest and trending posts in the same page, combine the two method calls into one controller method:

```
// BrowseController.php

public function getLatestAndTrending()
{
    $trendingPosts = $this->posts->getTrending(null, ['category' => Input::get('category'), 'timeframe' => Input::get('timeframe')]);

    $latestPosts = $this->posts->getLatest(null, ['category' => Input::get('category'), 'timeframe' => Input::get('timeframe')]);

    return View::make('post.list')
        ->with('title', t('New and trending'))
        ->with('trendingPosts', $trendingPosts)
        ->with('latestPosts', $latestPosts);
}
```

Change your route to point to the `getLatestAndTrending` controller method:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BrowseController@getLatestAndTrending']);
```

And then in your view, and can iterate over the trending and latest posts separately:

```
@foreach($trendingPosts as $post)
    // ...
@endforeach

@foreach($latestPosts as $post)
    // ...
@endforeach
```